# CC'ing my Boss's Boss

Tags: professionalism, email

I'm wondering about asking to take an seminar related to my job, but I'm concerned my "Branch MGR" won't approve due to the financial reasons. I'm debating on CC'ing her boss which is the regional MGR as I suspect he may approve, but I'm concerned my direct boss may not even "bring it upstairs" for consideration. Even if it was denied, I'd like to know the regional MGR see's my desire to gain knowledge.

Is this bad etiquette? Should I just send it to my direct boss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things you should consider:

First, CC'ing to one level above is almost always seen as some kind of escalation. You have to decide, if a training is worth this.

Second, there's a high chance that your boss's boss won't intervene, because your manager has the financial responsibility and the big boss doesn't want to undermine your manager's authority. And even, if the boss did intervene your manager won't like it and you caused this by CC'ing.

Comment: It's interesting that CC'ing above is viewed so negatively, as we almost always CC our bosses on every e-mail, but as this was a more "personal" request I felt it was a bit of a different situation. I did send it directly, well see how it goes, even if it's a no, I probably was better off not CC'ing above. Just the fact I felt I had to ask should have been a clue... Thanks @Simon!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Your Boss said no. So now your going over their head to get approval. Either The regional MGR overrides your bosses answer which undermines their authority, or they agree with your boss. Now your boss knows you don't care about their opinion because you tried to undermine their authority by asking the regional MGR.

Comment: Uhm... My boss didn't even read the email yet